# Reassemble jumbled method

Tags: ruby

Yesterday the kid next door, Jack, came over to recount an unfortunate experience he had and wondered if I could help him with his problem. He has been learning Ruby on his own (with a little help from me) and had just got a program to work after several days of hard work. Before saving the source he accidentally erased it.

Fortunately, he did have a print-out. Unfortunately, when he was at school his little sister took some scissors to his print-out. Here's a picture Jack took of her handiwork (after he had taped some of the cuttings together).

[image]

Jack wants me to help him put the program back together. I asked him to describe the problem he was working on but he was so upset that his answer was a complete muddle.

I've organised the information from the cuttings as follows.

```
code = [
  ["def doit *args"],             # position fixed
  ["y = [a,c,d].reduce", :block],
  [:left, :right],
  [:left, :right],
  ["args.rotate!"],  
  ["z = yield(a,b)"],
  ["args.reverse!"],  
  ["a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z"], # position fixed
  ["end"],                        # position fixed
  ["doit(1,21,13,4,55)", :block]  # position fixed
]
```

The order of the first line and last three lines is pretty obvious, but I don't know the order of the other lines. Two of the cuttings must be the left side of an assignment, two the right side of an assignment and two are blocks.

The six cuttings represented by `:left`, `:right` and `:block` in the array above are given in this hash:

```
pos = {
  left:  ["a,b,*_,c =", "d,e ="],
  right: ["args", "args.reverse"],
  block: ["{ |x,y| x+y }", "{ |x,y| x-y }"]  
}
```

Jack said the only other cutting, `#=> 275`, was the return value when he executed the method, so we might write

```
rv = 275
```

I considered trying different combinations but that seems like a hopeless task. Surely there must be a way to somehow automate the reconstruction of the code.

Can anybody help me with this? Suggestions would be OK, but I'd really like to see code.

Comment: Is this a serious question? If so, could you please remove all that irrelevant information?

Comment: Generate all possible permutations, evaluate each one (rescuing errors) and check whether it returns `275` (could be more than one).

Comment: @idmean, yes and no. Anything extraneous should waste no more than a few seconds of a reader's time.

Comment: Sounds fictional. :)

Comment: @sawa, "you can fool some of the people...". btw, smileys should have noses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you insist that this is a code writing service, and you would like to see some code, and I have some time to kill, and I like code that generates code, and none of us cares about reputation score any more, here's my attempt to reconstruct little Jack's hard work:

```
# jack_gen.rb
["a,b,*_,c =", "d,e ="].permutation do |l1, l2|
  ["args", "args.reverse"].permutation do |r1, r2|
    ["{ |x,y| x+y }", "{ |x,y| x-y }"].permutation do |b1, b2|
      [
        "  y = [a,c,d].reduce #{b1}",
        "  #{l1} #{r1}",
        "  #{l2} #{r2}",
        "  args.rotate!",
        "  z = yield(a,b)",
        "  args.reverse!"
      ].permutation do |lines|
        source = [
          "def doit *args",
          *lines,
          "  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z",
          "end",
          "doit(1,21,13,4,55) #{b2}"
        ].join("\n")

        rv = Object.new.instance_eval(source) rescue nil
        puts "\n#{source}\n#=> #{rv}" if rv == 275
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The program creates [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation)s of the 2 left-hand sides, 2 right-hand sides, 2 blocks and 6 non-fixed lines (2! × 2! × 2! × 6! = 5,760 possibilities). It then combines these into a source string (along with the fixed lines) consisting of method definition and method call. A new object is created and the string is evaluated in the context of that object using [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), rescuing exceptions that might occur due to undefined variables (about 80% of the generated methods are erroneous).

If the result (of the method call) is `275`, the corresponding source code is printed (along with the result).

We get 8 such programs:

```
$ ruby jack_gen.rb

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  z = yield(a,b)
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  z = yield(a,b)
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  z = yield(a,b)
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  z = yield(a,b)
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  z = yield(a,b)
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  z = yield(a,b)
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  z = yield(a,b)
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275

def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  z = yield(a,b)
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275
```

4 of these programs are in fact duplicates because of `#{l1} #{r1}` / `#{l2} #{r2}` (hat tip to [Register Sole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225749/reassemble-jumbled-method#comment97189659_55227315)) – it would have been enough to make the right-hand side variable, i.e. `"  a,b,*_,c = #{r1}"` / `"  d,e = #{r2}"`.

The remaining 4 programs differ only in the position of `z = yield(a, b)`. Assuming that Jack assigns his variables alphabetically, we can pick the one which has `z =` *after* `y =`:

```
def doit *args
  args.reverse!
  a,b,*_,c = args
  args.rotate!
  d,e = args.reverse
  y = [a,c,d].reduce { |x,y| x-y }
  z = yield(a,b)
  a-2*b+7*c-3*d+30*e-2*y+6*z
end
doit(1,21,13,4,55) { |x,y| x+y }
#=> 275
```

Comment: There is only 1 possible set value of a, b, c, d, e, y, z that satisfy the result, and it can be achieved in 4 combinations (which differs only by where the z assignment is). You got 8 combinations probably because there are two identical `[:left, :right]` blocks posted in the question?

Comment: @RegisterSole good catch! I'll leave the fix to Jack as an exercise.

Comment: Nicely done, well-organised code. Jack will be pleased. (That's quite a run-on sentence. You'd be scolded by an English teacher, but I like it.)